# FIFO (named pipe) messaging obstacles

Tags: python, linux, unix, pipe, named-pipes

I plan to use Unix named pipes (mkfifo) for simple multi-process messaging.
A message would be just a single line of text.

Would you discourage me from that? What obstacles should I expect?

I have noticed these limitations:

1. A sender cannot continue until the message is received.
2. A receiver is blocked until there are some data. Nonblocking IO would be needed
   when we need to stop the reading. For example, another thread could ask for that.
3. The receiver could obtain many messages in a single read. These have to be processed
   before quiting.
4. The max length of an atomic message is limited by 4096 bytes. That is the PIPE_BUF limit on Linux (see man 7 pipe).

I will implement the messaging in Python. But the obstacles hold in general.

Comment: How many processes do you expect to use the pipe at the same time? If you have more than one reader, a written message would be seen by only one of the readers, AFAIR. (Not 100% sure on this one)

Comment: @rodion -- Yes, it is intended to see a message just in one reader. The FIFO works that way.

Comment: Why is blocking a problem?  I can see a non-blocking write.  I can't see the point of a non-blocking read when you're waiting for work.

Comment: There are many instances you'd want a non-blocking read (which you use select for). For instance, multiple writer different pipes, so you don't want to block on just one. Another one would be if your work wasn't "request based", like if you got updates via a pipe, wanted to keep working while waiting for them. A third would be if you could process groups of messages at once, so you want to get all that are available.

Comment: I'll by a "fan-in" (multiple input FIFOs), that makes sense.  Not request based doesn't make sense in this specific context.  Batches don't make sense; the pipeline's buffering is all the "batching" you'll ever need.

Comment: @Todd -- Thanks for your comment. It provides good hits when to use the nonblocking IO. I'm OK with the nonblocking IO, it will allow to stop the receiver thread at any time. I use poll().

Comment: Versus  '4096 bytes', expect bigger, say 65536 bytes. The OP's suggested  'man 7 pipe' mentions the change good as of linux kernel release 2.6.11  -- which was back in 2005.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Lack of portability - they are mainly a Unix thing. Sockets are more portable.
2. Harder to scale out to multiple systems (another sockets+)
3. On the other hand, I believe pipes are faster than sockets for processes on the same machine (less communication overhead).

As to your limitations,

1. You can "[select](http://docs.python.org/library/select.html)" on pipes, to do a non-blocking read.
2. I normally (in perl) print out my messages on pipes seperated by "\n", and read a line from them to get one message at a time.
3. Do be careful with the atomic length.

I find [perlipc](http://search.cpan.org/~nwclark/perl-5.8.9/pod/perlipc.pod) to be a good discussion between the various options, though it has perl specific code.

Comment: The readline() in a receiver will not save you from holding multiple messages in an internal buffer. They should still be processed before quiting.

Answer (score 4):

The blocking, both on the sender side and the receiver side, can be worked around via non-blocking I/O.

Further limitations of FIFOs:

- Only one client at a time.
- After the client closes the FIFO, the server need to re-open its endpoint.
- Unidirectional.

I would use [UNIX domain sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket) instead, which have none of the above limitations.

As an added benefit, if you want to scale it to communicate between multiple machines, it's barely any change at all.  For example, just take the Python documentation page on [socket](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket-example) and replace `socket.AF_INET` with `socket.AF_UNIX`, `(HOST, PORT)` with `filename`, and it *just works*.

`SOCK_STREAM` will give you stream-like behavior; that is, two sends may be merged into one receive or vice versa.  `AF_UNIX` also supports `SOCK_DGRAM`: datagrams are guaranteed to be sent and read all as one unit or not at all.  (Analogously, `AF_INET`+`SOCK_STREAM`=TCP, `AF_INET`+`SOCK_DGRAM`=UDP.)

Comment: What do you mean by "Only one client at a time"?
I could have multiple writers and readers on a FIFO.

Comment: You have to open the FIFO for reading multiple times.  Accepting new connections on the same listening socket is much cleaner.

Comment: Just FYI, apparently on some unix platforms (Solaris) FIFOs are bidirectional.. but your point is valid.  Use unix domain sockets instead.

Comment: On the writer side, you can't open a named pipe for writing in non-blocking mode unless there's a reader already present (you get ENXIO). OTOH, on the reader side I've not seen any indication that the writer finishing causes any problems.